# SQL Query for Json object inside Json

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, sql-server-2019

I have the below Json string. I need to write a query to get the SP records. Without providing the 
 index value, we need get the result.

```
 {
   "S": [
    {
      "Name": "Project1",
       "SP": [
        {
          "ID": 1,
          "Name": "Test1"
        },
        {
          "ID": 2,
          "Name": "Test2"
        },
  }]}
```

How do I query to get the SP values.

```
Expected Result:

 ID    Name 
 1     Test1 
 2     Test2

 I tried the below but not working. Can you please suggest the correct query.

SELECT DISTINCT JSON_VALUE(JsonData, '$.S[0].SP.ID') AS ID,
                JSON_VALUE(JsonData, '$.S[0].SP.Name') AS Name
    FROM TableA
```

Comment: which SQL engine are you using?

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2019

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `JSON_QUERY` nested in `OPENJSON` function containing `WITH` Clause in order to visit all members of `SP` array dynamically :

```
SELECT ID, Name
  FROM TableA
 CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(JSON_QUERY(JsonData, '$.S[0].SP'))
             WITH (ID   nvarchar(500) '$.ID',
                   Name nvarchar(500) '$.Name')
```

Btw, you need to fix the JsonData as converting to

```
{
   "S": [
    {
      "Name": "0219 Project Methodology - Allergies",
       "SP": [
        {
          "ID": 1,
          "Name": "Test1"
        },
        {
          "ID": 2,
          "Name": "Test2"
        }
  ] } ] }
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a012ac09f28f94a494554595b217b7c5)</kbd>

Comment: How we can query, if there was one more json object inside SP?

Comment: Hi @AshokYaganti , Can you add this as a new question containig a sample JSON, please ?

Comment: Sure @Barbaros Ozhan

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61268901/sql-query-on-json-object-inside-multiple-json-objects