# SQL Query on Json object inside multiple JSON objects

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, sql-server-2019, open-json

I have the below Json string. I need to write a query to get the TP records. Without providing the index value, we need get the result.

```
{
   "S": [
    {
      "Name": "Project1",
      "SP": [
       {
          "ID": 1,
          "Name": "Test1",
          "TP": [
            {
              "TID": 11,
              "TName": "TT1",
            },
            {
              "TID": 12,
              "TName": "TT2",
            },
         ]
      },
      {
        "ID": 2,
        "Name": "Test2",
        "TP": [
         {
          "TID": 13,
          "TName": "TT3",
         },
         {
          "TID": 14,
          "TName": "TT4",
         },
       ]
    },
  ]}]}
```

How do I query to get the TP values.

Expected Result:

```
  TID    TName 
  11     TT1 
  12     TT2
  13     TT3
  14     TT4
```

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2019

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `OPENJSON` function containing `WITH` Clause added as many `CROSS APPLY` Clause as upto see all sub-arrays :

```
SELECT S3.TID, S3.TName
  FROM tab
 CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(JsonData)
             WITH ( S  nvarchar(max) '$.S' AS JSON) AS S0
 CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (S0.S) 
             WITH (
                    SP nvarchar(max) '$.SP' AS JSON ) S1
 CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (S1.SP) 
             WITH (
                    TP nvarchar(max) '$.TP' AS JSON ) S2
 CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (S2.TP) 
             WITH (
                    TID   nvarchar(500) '$.TID', 
                    TName nvarchar(500) '$.TName' ) S3
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=50a3068d9329a458b85f8459e252ccc4)</kbd>

**Update :** If the first array `S` is fixed to contain only one item, we can reduce one-step as

```
SELECT S3.TID, S3.TName
  FROM tab
 CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(JsonData)
             WITH (
                    SP nvarchar(max) '$.S[0].SP' AS JSON ) S1
 CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (S1.SP) 
             WITH (
                    TP nvarchar(max) '$.TP' AS JSON ) S2
 CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (S2.TP) 
             WITH (
                    TID   nvarchar(500) '$.TID', 
                    TName nvarchar(500) '$.TName' ) S3
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6cfa08d08003a7cad1594281a44eed96)</kbd>

Comment: Is there any easy way to get the count? In the above Json, SP records are one and TP records 4 like that.

Comment: well, I don't know easier way, difficult to handle S, SP, TP ,by which arrays start and because of this, we cannot combine the paths such as $.S.SP.TP at one step @AshokYaganti .